# Searching by meta values showing inappropriate result

Tags: search, post-meta, meta-query

I am working on a custom search by meta value and using this:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property_post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
                     'relation' => 'OR',
                     array(
                      'key' => 'custom_textarea',
                      'value' => 'me',  // if I use static keyword it works
                      'compare' => 'LIKE'
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_price',
                      'value' => array( $_REQUEST['custom_price'], $_REQUEST['custom_price1'] ),
                      'type' => 'numeric',
                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_beds',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_beds'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_bath',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_bath'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_garage',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_garage'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      )
                      )

);
```

If I use some static keyword for meta value then it works, but with `$_REQUEST` it doesn't. I checked `$_REQUEST` using `print_r($_REQUEST)`:

```
Array ( [custom_textarea] => aa[custom_price] => 1000 [custom_price1] => 4000[custom_beds] => 2[custom_garage] => 1)
```

So what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Does the issue only happen to "custom_textarea" field?

Comment: If i assign static value then it works

Comment: I know by default type is CHAR. But I wonder if `'type' => 'CHAR'` for `'custom_textarea'` works or not?

Comment: Does wrapping your LIKE values in %% help? e.g. `'%'.$_REQUEST['custom_textarea'].'%'` ?

Comment: I also cant help but notice your static value is not the same as the value in your request array

Comment: did you see any bug in my code.... am I using right procedure for filter searching..... @Tom J Nowell

Comment: More your testing regime. You're testing static values with the value 'me', and then you're using 'aa' to test non static values. You should use the same for both if you want a valid test.

Comment: Can you share the SQL query, both from your static test and also from the dynamic test? i.e. `$query = WP_Query( $args ); echo $query->request;`

Comment: Exactly what is the "inappropriate result"?

Comment: inappropriate result means, the meta query do not show exact search result for $_REQUEST['custom_textarea'], $_REQUEST['custom_beds'] , $_REQUEST['custom_bath']  ....etc  @s_ha_dum

Comment: you can ask if i have something missing here to get people know my problem becouse now I am totally fed off and do not know what is the error in my code ... :( Help !

Answer (score 2):

First of all, one never should rely on *raw* `$_REQUEST`: believe me, this is a security issue.

PHP has 2 functions: [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and [`filter_input_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) that helps you to sanitize your request data.

In addition, in your request dump I don't see any `$_REQUEST['custom_bath']`, but you are using that value, that can be a cause for the issue. You should check that a variable is setted before use it.

Using my suggestions your code becomes something like this

```
$args = array(
  'custom_textarea'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  'custom_price'      => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
  'custom_price1'     => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
  'custom_beds'       => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  'custom_bath'       => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  'custom_garage'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);

$get = filter_input_array( INPUT_GET, $args, TRUE );
$post = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args, TRUE );
$request = array_merge( $get, $post );

$query_args = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

if ( ! empty( $request['custom_textarea'] ) ) {
   $query_args[] = array(
     'key' => 'custom_textarea',
     'value' => "%{$request['custom_textarea']}%", 
     'compare' => 'LIKE'
   );
}

if ( ! empty( $request['custom_price'] ) && ! empty($request['custom_price1']) ) {
   $query_args[] = array(
     'key' => 'custom_price',
     'value' => array( "{$request['custom_price']}", "{$request['custom_price1']}" ), 
     'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
     'type'    => 'SIGNED'
   );
}

if ( ! empty( $request['custom_beds'] ) ) {
   $query_args[] = array(
     'key' => 'custom_beds',
     'value' => "{$request['custom_beds']}", 
   );
}

if ( ! empty( $request['custom_bath'] ) ) {
   $query_args[] = array(
     'key' => 'custom_bath',
     'value' => "{$request['custom_bath']}", 
   );
}   

if ( ! empty( $request['custom_garage'] ) ) {
   $query_args[] = array(
     'key' => 'custom_garage',
     'value' => "{$request['custom_garage']}", 
   );
} 

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Comment: not working, I have custom post 'property_post'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you have a string variable Wordpress doesn't automatically add quotes to the variable and therefore the search filter doesn't generate any result.

I suggest the following answer.

```
$custom_textarea = '\''.$_REQUEST['custom_textarea'].'\'';  // declare a variable something like this.
```

And then your `meta_query` would be:

```
'meta_query' => array(
                     'relation' => 'OR',
                     array(
                      'key' => 'custom_textarea',
                      'value' => $custom_textarea, 
                      'compare' => 'LIKE'
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_price',
                      'value' => array( $_REQUEST['custom_price'], $_REQUEST['custom_price1'] ),
                      'type' => 'numeric',
                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_beds',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_beds'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_bath',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_bath'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_garage',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_garage'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      )
                      )
```

Comment: did not help..................... :(\

Comment: if you are doing `LIKE` comparison I would suggest using `%` as well. Else for exact comparison use `=`.

Answer (score 0):

For mine, I use it like so on search results page:

```
$pricemax = $_POST['price'];
```

then in the query...

```
array(
        'key' => 'custom_rent',
        'value' => array('', $pricemax),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
```

Does this help? Try using $_POST rather than $_REQUEST?